# Error when cloning from bitbucket repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, clone, atlassian-sourcetree

I’m trying to clone my git repo from bitbucket into my sourcetree, but seem to be getting an error from trying to clone.
This is the result of the error:

```
git -c filter.lfs.smudge= -c filter.lfs.required=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks clone --branch default <repo>
Cloning into 'E:\Projects\cmainfo_main'...
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Completed with errors, see above.
```

I’m not exactly sure what is wrong I have tried using different git commands to see if that would work but unfortunately, it didn't go right.
I'm not sure if it’s because of an antivirus issue or an internet issue because the repo might be fairly big, but when the repos were mercurial ones they were able to clone on my pc. 
Unfortunately, I'm really new to the whole git issue.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't give too much off that information, I can tell you that this is the root cause: `fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly`.

In other words: bitbucket unexpectedly closed the connection to your computer without telling you why.
This shouldn't be happening, there might be something in place with your internet (if you have just a shoddy connection), or a firewall trying to muck things up.

What does your clone URL start with? `https://` or something different like `ssh://` or `git@`?

If it's `ssh://` or `git@`, meaning you're doing a clone over SSH not HTTP, it could be because bitbucket is refusing your SSH client version or listed encryption protocols.